# resuming and uploading files with wcf

Tags: wcf, file, uploading

I'm building an application to upload files from clients to a server using wcf and I'm trying to implement a way to resume the upload if connection fails. Suppose I have a 500 KB file, the upload begins and connection fails, only 100 KB were copied. When I resume, the server application knows it has 100 KB.

When I read the stream transmitted with code like this:

```
while ((bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)) > 0)
```

1. Is that 0 (offset) the byte where I begin to read??
2. If so, should I begin to read from 100?? something like:

   while ((bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 100, bufferSize)) > 0)

and then append bytes to the existing incomplete file??

This is my code:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\" + name, FileMode.Append))
{
    int bufferSize = 4 * 1024; // 4KB buffer
    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int bytes;

    while ((bytes = stream.Read(buffer, 100, bufferSize)) > 0)
    {
        fs.Write(buffer, 100, bytes);
        fs.Flush();
    }
    stream.Close();
    fs.Close();
}
```

What changes do I have to make??

Answer (score 0):

No, the offset specifies where in the buffer to begin to COPY the bytes that are read from the stream.

What you may want to do is Seek.  `Stream.Seek(100, SeekOrigin.Begin);`
This has the effect of "skipping" the first 100 bytes in the stream.
At that point, you will want to begin reading....

If you do this resume thing, then I suggest using a CRC or MD5 or something, to verify the contents of the file after completion.

Comment: I get an exception, the method is not supported. CanSeek property is set to false.